# RestFull WCF Service for POST Method HTML form

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest

I have created a RestFul WCF Webservice and have also deployed it. I'm able to consume the GET method data but I'm not able to consume the POST method data, it always provides me with the bad request response.

```
     [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "BookAppointment")]
        AppointmentBookAndCancelResult BookAppointment(AppointmentBookAndCancelInPut input);
```

Here is my HTML Form for this RestFul WCF service

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://192.168.15.45:8083/TaqeemServices.svc/BookAppointment" Method="POST">

 <input name="AppointmentNumber" type="text" value="APP-00000003-H042S5"/>
<input name="UserId" type="text" value="4"/>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I get this error response always:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

What is wrong?

Code for AppointmentBookAndCancelInPut :

```
 [DataContract]
    public class AppointmentBookAndCancelInPut
    {
        string userId = string.Empty;
        string appointmentNumber = string.Empty;

        [DataMember]
        public string UserId
        {
            get { return userId; }
            set { userId = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string AppointmentNumber
        {
            get { return appointmentNumber; }
            set { appointmentNumber = value; }
        }
    }
```

According to Shah I have made the `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>` in web.config file and when I run the post method I get the detailed output

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. 
The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. 
The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. 
This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. 
See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. 
See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: 

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: I'm not able to tell you definitively what's wrong, but I can offer you some help in the form of WCF trace logging. If you follow the instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420538/Simple-Steps-to-Enable-Tracing-in-WCF) you'll be able to see the error that's occurring and all the call stack information associated with it. Perhaps then you'll be able to give us more details or even be able to solve the problem without any further guidance at all! :-)

Comment: Please post the code for AppointmentBookAndCancelInPut

Comment: please add these to your web.config and refresh<servicebehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehaviorName">
          <servicedebug includeexceptiondetailinfaults="true" />
        </behavior>
</servicebehaviors>

Comment: @Shah I have made the <servicedebug includeexceptiondetailinfaults="true"/> and I have updated my question with the output I received after making that changes. It seems I've to pass the data in xml format but what could be the procedure

Answer (score 0):

WCF Web services uses WebHttpBinding that work with Json or XML representation. In your case you are sending data sthm like this:

```
-----------------------------7de175231090e00
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AppointmentNumber"

APP-00000003-H042S5
-----------------------------7de175231090e00
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UserId"

4 
-----------------------------7de175231090e00--
```

which is definitely not json or xml representation.

Comment: Thats right but how would I send it in xml representation?

Comment: Either delegate sending and encoding data to EcmaScript(JS) or use `Stream` in your server operation and delegate decoding that stream to server (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dde73561-29c0-4c34-b18a-990ae114b92c/how-would-i-do-the-following-form-post-with-wcf-rest).